# Call Rest API inside powershell function

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I have called Rest API using powershell function but i need to get date entry from all objects like english-and-wales, scotland , northern ireland. using this $list.'england-and-wales'.events.date i will get only england-and-wales details but remaining scotland, northern ireland date i am unable to fetch

```
function Get-Holiday {
  Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri https://www.gov.uk/bank-holidays.json

}
$list = Get-Holiday
$list | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 3
$list.'england-and-wales'.events.date
```

I need to get date entry from all england-and-wales, scotland, northern ireland. can you please provide solution for that

Example image

[image]

Comment: Please don't post duplicate questions with multiple accounts. I've answered [the other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64889361/rename-file-name-alternate-weekdays-using-powershell-functions)

Comment: And honestly, the question seem to make less sense for every iteration.

Comment: instead of fetching only $list.england-and-wales.events.date , i need remaining $list.scotland.event.date and $list.northernirelandevent.date. multiple times i am writing this one but i dont want to write multiple times. thats solution i need. please consider my request

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to combine the dates from all three data sets, you could do something like this:

```
# define divisions
$divisions = 'england-and-wales', 'scotland', 'northern-ireland'

# fetch data 
$list = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri https://www.gov.uk/bank-holidays.json

# enumerate dates for all divisions, remove duplicates and assign to a variable
$allPossibleHolidayDates = $divisions |%{ $list.$_.events.date} |Sort -Unique
```

At which point you can determine whether a certain date is a holiday by:

```
# Get a string representing todays date formatted like "2020-11-18"
$todaysDate = Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd'

# this will now return $true if today is a holiday in any of the divisions
$allPossibleHolidayDates -contains $todaysDate
```

Comment: I added my error screenshot please find above. i tried but getting error 
The property '$divisions' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists.
At line:4 char:3
+   $list.'$divisions'.events[0]
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], PropertyNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFoundStrict

Comment: can u please provide solution for my issue

Comment: @HafizahChannel Look closely to the code Mathias provided and compare that to your own. See the mistake you made? Have the function return `$divisions |%{ $list.$_.events.date} | Sort -Unique`